# How can I serialize list with an object relation produced from queryset TruncYear in Django 1.11

Tags: django, postgresql, serialization, time-series, django-1.11

I manage to get time series data with TruncYear/TruncMonth/TruncDay/etc like below from Tracking table. However the data for the venue just produce the venue_id. I would like to have that serialized so that it returns the "name" from the relation Venue table.

I am using Django 1.11 a postgres 9.4

Here is my time series code:

```
tracking_in_timeseries_data = Tracking.objects.annotate(
                                          year=TruncYear('created_at')).values('year', 'venue_id').annotate(
                                            count=Count('employee_id',
                                                        distinct = True)).order_by('year')   


return Response(tracking_in_timeseries_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

currently it output like this:

```
[
    {
      "venue_id": 4,
      "year": "2017-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "venue_id": 2,
      "year": "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "venue_id": 6,
      "year": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "count": 1
    }
  ]
```

I want to explode venue data to return the id & name like this:

```
  [
    {
      "venue": {
                id: 4,
                name: "room A"
                },
      "year": "2017-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "venue": {
                id: 2,
                name: "room B"
                },
      "year": "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "venue": {
                id: 6,
                name: "room C"
                },
      "year": "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "count": 1
    }
  ]
```

How to explode the "venue" to return the id and name ? The name is useful for presentation purpose.

UPDATE (here are some attempts that failed):

this only displays count but accumulative ( https://gist.github.com/axilaris/0cd86cec0edf675d654eadb3aff5b066). something weird and not sure why.

```
class TimeseriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    venue = VenueNameSerializer(source="venue_id",many=False, read_only=True)
    year = serializers.TimeField(read_only=True)
    count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tracking
        fields = ("venue",
                  "year",
                  "count")


class TimeseriesSerializer(serializers.Serializer): <-- here is another try but doesnt work serializers.Serializer

    venue_id = VenueNameSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    year = serializers.TimeField(read_only=True)
    count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
```

I think the answer is quite close to this: [django rest framework serialize a dictionary without create a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803073/django-rest-framework-serialize-a-dictionary-without-create-a-model)

FYI, this is my actual code (must as well put it here) for the test, names may differ slightly but the whole intention is the same. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/919d1a20d3e799101a8cf6aeb4d120b5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to create a serializer for the Venue which displays the `id` and `name` fields and use it as a field in the `TrackingSerializer`.

In your case there is something more to consider: since you are using `values` to group, what you get from the queryset is not a `Tracking` object, thus your `venue_id` can't be translated to a `Venue` object by DRF.

To fix this you need to override the `to_representation` method of `VenueSerializer` to get the `Venue` object from its primary key.

I'm including models and views to give you a working example, but you probably only need serializers and the adjusted queryset from the view.

### Models

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Tracking(models.Model):
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

### Views

```py
class TrackingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = (
        Tracking.objects
        .annotate(
            year=ExtractYear('created_at'),
        )
        .values('year', 'venue')
        .annotate(
            count=Count('employee_id', distinct=True),
        )
        .order_by('year')
    )
    serializer_class = TrackingSerializer
```

### Serializers

```py
class VenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = ['id', 'name']

    def to_representation(self, value):
        value = Venue.objects.get(pk=value)
        return super(VenueSerializer, self).to_representation(value)


class TrackingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    venue = VenueSerializer(read_only=True)
    year = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    count = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tracking
        fields = ['venue', 'year', 'count']
```

Note that I replaced your `TruncYear` with `ExtractYear`, the difference between the two is that the former returns a datetime, the latter an int which is what you want I guess.

If you prefer to use `TruncYear` you will have to replace:

```py
year = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
```

with:

```py
year = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
```

in `TrackingSerializer`.

Comment: It didnt work, the output looks like this https://gist.github.com/axilaris/0cd86cec0edf675d654eadb3aff5b066. I think it accumulates altogether in the count. Also, I prefer TruncYear than ExtractYear. reason is because i need to use for others like TruncDay, TruncHour.

Comment: It should work, please show your updated serializers and views

Comment: this is my actual code: https://gist.github.com/axilaris/919d1a20d3e799101a8cf6aeb4d120b5. naming might be slightly difference, but i'ved applied all the relevant. but must as well share the actual code here (i'ved also now put it up in update).

Comment: referesh this link, added more info https://gist.github.com/axilaris/919d1a20d3e799101a8cf6aeb4d120b5

Comment: Why you are serializing twice? Try passing directly `serializer.data` to the response skipping the second serialization