# How can I pass dictionary in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In django, I was able to pass data using dictionary. Like I set the objects in my dictionary and pass it in return render and call the object in frontend (return render(request, 'c.html', context) right? so How can I do this in django rest?

Answer (score 4):

You may return Response in rest framework like this if you are using django rest framework.

```
context = {'key':'value'}
return Response(context)
```

Or if you are using a serializer then

```
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: So how can I pass two serializer at the same time in one view? Suppose I have two serializer, one is product serializer which contain all products and another serializer for related products, in the individual product page i want to show product info and related products so now how am I gonna pass related product info?

Comment: You can create context with both the serializers data. 
`context = {
'product':product_serializer.data, 
'related_products': related_products_serializer.data
}
return Response(context)`

Answer (score 0):

In Django REST Framework the concept of Serializing is to convert DB data to a datatype that can be used by javascript. Every serializer comes with some field that is going to be processed. For example, if you have a class with the name Employee and its fields as Employee_id, Employee_name, is_admin, etc. Then, you would need AutoField, CharField, and BooleanField for storing and manipulating data through Django. Similarly, serializer also works with the same principle and has fields that are used to create a serializer.

DictField is basically a dictionary field that validates the input against a dictionary of objects. It has the following arguments:

child and allow_empty like this>>>

```
field_name = serializers.DictField(*args, **kwargs)
```

for example `document = DictField(child=CharField())`

you can use serializer like below>>>

```
from rest_framework import serializer
class Any(object):
    def __init__(self, dictonary):
        self.dict = dictionary
class AnySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    dictionary = serializers.DictField(
    child = serializers.CharField())
```

you can visit [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803073/django-rest-framework-serialize-a-dictionary-without-create-a-model) for understanding through the real problem.

And this [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) is the complete documentation of your problem. You can check this out.

Comment: So how can I pass two serializer at the same time in one view? Suppose I have two serializer, one is product serializer which contain all products and another serializer for related products, in the individual product page i want to show product info and related products so now how am I gonna pass related product info?

Comment: you can use @AshinShakya solution for that on his comment.